# Change the value of a global object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, global-variables

I know that this question was asked a lot of times and I read a lot of the answers about this. But I'm not able to update this global property object in the right way.

Here is a little fragment of the code

```
var character = {
  image: "",
  gender: "",
  name: "",
  past: "",
  job: "",
  health: 0,
  mana: 0,
  hit: 0
};

/* character creation, first module */

$(".select").on("click", function firstSection() {
  $(".select").slideUp();
  character.gender = (this.id);
  alert(character.gender);
  $(".section1").fadeOut();
  $(".section2").show();

});

$(".textPast").on("click", function secondModule() {
  var color = $(this).css("background-color");

  control();

  $(this).css("background", "white");
  $(this).css("color", "black");
  character.past = (this.id);
  count++;
  check++;
});
```

The problem is:

When I exit from the function `firstModule` or I try to alert the property `character.gender` in another js file, and after that I've launched the function `firstModule` the value of `character.gender` doesn't change.

Where is my error? What could I do to fix it?

I saw these topics about this question:

- global scope
- reference and value in JavaScript
- asynchronous flow

Are they correct?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/legeo/pen/vaoZrj)

Comment: are you loading first and second module in different pages? if yes, then global variable will not work, you should try with localStorage

Comment: When passing functions as arguments to `.on()`, the functions are passed as anonymous functions - the names you've added don't have any meaning. If you want to have named functions, declare them separately and then just pass the name of the function as the argument. Also, please edit your question to show the relevant HTML and CSS as well, so we can replicate your issue.

Comment: Also, you mention exiting from `firstModule`, but you haven't posted anything with that identifier.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for all these answers. I update the post with Codepen. the problem is that if I try to use the object {character} in another file, different from this one, the object is equal to its start condition, though this file is open after all the functions and animations that you can see in the javascript code.Like the global variable isn't update during all the process. I hope I was enough clear. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localStorage to set an Item, in this case, an Object and get that item in another page onload and assign it to the local object, whenever you modify the properties of the object replace the localStorage object.